# Exportar dados do FireBird

Tags: sql, firebird, exportação

Tenho um programa de cadastro de clientes ligado ao Firebird, porém não vou mais usar esse programa e preciso dos dados.
Teria como eu pegar o arquivo database.fbd, que receio que esteja todos os cadastros e gerar algum excel ou coisa do tipo com todas as informações?
Ou instalar algum gerenciador do próprio banco e abrir as tabelas lá?

Comment: Baixa o [flame robin](http://www.flamerobin.org/) para acessar a base de dados, lembra que você do usuário e senha para conexão.

Answer (score 2):

Instale o `Firebird` com ferramenta de servidor na maquina aonde deseja abrir, e utilize a ferramente `IBExpert` para abrir o banco de dados.

Se você não configurou uma senha no `Firebird` a senha será masterkey, senão você entrara na base com a senha que definiu.

Apos conseguir acesso basta abrir a tabela ir em Data, e depois clicar no botão de exportar conforme a imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Assim como voce pode utilizar a ferramenta IBExpert, existe tambem o software

```
Fullconvert https://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/howto-pt/firebird-to-excel
```

que faz a conversao de Firebird (arquivos relacionados: fdb, ib, gdb)

para  Excel, Microsoft Excel (arquivos relacionados xls, xlsx)